# Qt: Hand over a parameter to a PHP script and execute the script

Tags: php, qt, push-notification

I would like to run a PHP script with Qt. This script is an normal .php file which tries to access the adress. How can I hand over some parameter to a script and execute this script with the corresponding parameter?

Does the following implemention work?

```
QProcess::execute("User/Desktop/", QStringList() << "script.php");
```

How can I check, if the script was executed?

Would be a great pleasure, if anybody can help me.

Kind regards

Comment: you're executing it as a shell script, basically, so you can pass stuff on the command line, e.g. `$ ./foo.php arg1 arg2 arg3`, or you could mod the script to read parameters from somewhere, e.g. stdin.

Comment: How can I execute it as shell script if I created a Qt-Widget application? Didn't start my project as console application